# Highstock grouping

Tags: padding, highcharts

I want to draw stocks like in the image below:

[image: desired]

If I use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/67BkD/34/) solution:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {           
        pointWidth: 20,
        groupPadding: 0.75
    }
}
```

columns of different series are stretching when the whole container is getting wider.
Is there a way to make only distance between groups scalable (marked red) and keep two columns in one group always close?

[image: current]

Comment: Setting pointWidth disable groupPadding. You can instead set pointPadding only, see: http://jsfiddle.net/67BkD/35/
 However, this is still not perfect solution.

Comment: @Paweł Fus, thank you very much! So, then I still can not set `pointWidth` parameter, right? Now my columns are twice wider though it is more suitable for me, but being able to adjust column width would be just perfect.

Comment: You can add own suggestions on [Highcharts UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general)

Answer (score 0):

3d charts are not supported, but you can vote for it here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/889125-3d-charts